# Project in Xcode using git submodules results in conflicts

Tags: xcode, git, xcode4, git-submodules

I have a big project I'm working on which makes use of git submodules to separate a lot of the code I write. Problem is I ended up getting a conflict in Xcode because of two different versions of the same submodule.

For example, imagine I have the repository Project which has a submodule SubA and a submodule SubB. The problem is that my SubA has a submodule SubB too. This could not be a problem if the two different SubB's are in the same revision, but leads to conflicts when they aren't.

When importing all the files into Xcode there is no problem since they're in two different folders, but I use

```
#import "FileInSubB.h"
```

to import source code in SubB, so Xcode will compile only one of the versions of that file because they have the same name. Is there an easy solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

First, why would you have two submodules subB if they aren't the same? I mean naming has the goal of making a difference between things: you call apples and pears by their name, if they were both called apple how would you know which one to take?

If the submodules subB are the same, why do you have two? or maybe it's not possible to have two modules sharing the same submodule? (I doubt it though, since that's a point of using submodules)

Second, and more for you to get an answer, in Xcode, don't you have dependies or some thing like that, to target one path (i.e. have a dependency to path/to/subB_v1 in the compiler settings).

Comment: Because SubB is, for example, a repository with a Utilities class. I use it in SubA and Project. And during development of SubA I don't know if SubB is a submodule of Project or even if Project is going to use SubA. They're developed separately.

I don't know if Xcode has build dependencies, I'll look into it, thank you.

Comment: but then why don't you point to the same SubB? or maybe I didn't get something. I mean I think submodules are like dependencies, you can point to them from different projects, and once you update the submodule, all the projects can see the new version. I never used submodules but I assume that's how it works

Comment: Because I may want the two SubB to be in different revisions.

Comment: all right. Just for curiosity, did you try to point to two different versions, like branching or something like that? I am just wondering if it would be possible.